# Semicontinuity of Exts

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, semicontinuity

Let $Z$ be a proper noetherian scheme over an algebraically closed field $k$, and $S$ a smooth scheme over $k$. Let $\cal E$, $\cal F$ be coherent sheaves on $Z\times S$, flat over $S$. Is it true that for any $s\in S$ and integer $i$, $\text{Ext}^i_{{\cal O}_Z}({\cal E}_s,{\cal F}_s)$ is finite dimensional over $k$, and that
$$s\mapsto\dim(\text{Ext}^i_{{\cal O}_Z}({\cal E}_s,{\cal F}_s))$$
is upper semicontinuous ?  (I have seen this only for projective schemes).

Comment: In the complex geometry case, I remembered that it is somewhere in *Variation der globalen Ext in Deformationen kompakter komplexer Räume*.

Comment: I cannot recall a precise reference, but it should follow from combining  https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08IF and https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08EU with Theorem 7.6.9 of EGAIII-2.

Comment: Thank you very much for these answers